# What is the difference between these two limits, one with $\lim\limits_{x\to0^{+}}$, the other with $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I don't need an exact answer, I just need to know how these two limits would affect the answer and if there is a huge difference on how they are worked out, if they have a different step-by-step solution.

1. $\large \lim\limits_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{x}{\tan(7x)}$
2. $\large \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\tan(7x)}$

Comment: do you know the value of $\tan(0)$ ?

Comment: @reuns Yes, it is 0, I just need to know if I can still use the Limit Laws on #1 as I would on #2.

Comment: do you know the value of $\tan'(0)$ ? do you know a theorem about $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{x}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The function
$$
x \longmapsto f(x)=\frac{x}{\tan (7x)} 
$$ is **even**, thus **in this case**
$$
\lim_{\large x \to 0^-}\frac{x}{\tan (7x)} =\lim_{\large x \to 0^+}\frac{x}{\tan (7x)}=\lim_{\large x \to 0}\frac{x}{\tan (7x)}=\frac17\lim_{\large x \to 0}\frac{7x}{\tan (7x)}=\frac17
$$ where we have used the standard result
$$
\lim_{\large x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}x=1.
$$

Comment: @Oliver , Why are you multiplying by 1/7?

Comment: @SamPerales Because I know that $\lim_{\large u \to 0}\frac{\tan u}{u}=1$, and as I have $u=7x$, I need a factor $7$ to obtain $u$... Hoping it is clear now for you. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see. The main goal was to get the `tan x` to the top.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is if you have to worry about asymptotes. the first one the limit evaluated as x approaches 0 from the right. It doesn't worry about the left portion of the limit. However, the second one includes what happens as x approaches 0 from the left side as well as the right.